# Format string vulnerability and input strings

Tags: c, string, security, exploit, format-string

Assume I have the following program:

```
#include  <stdio.h>
#include  <string.h>
#include  <stdlib.h>

int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
    char buf [100];
    snprintf ( buf, sizeof buf, argv [1] ) ;
    buf [ sizeof buf -1 ] = 0;
    printf ( "%s \n" , buf ) ;
    return 0 ;
}
```

If I compile and run it:

```
gcc test.c -o test
./test %p%p%p
(nil)0x4006d00x7f67e05b7ab0
```

I can see the stack values, meaning that it is affected by the format string vulnerability.

Now, let's slightly modify the above code:

```
#include  <stdio.h>
#include  <string.h>
#include  <stdlib.h>

int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
    char buf [100];
    printf ( "%s \n" , argv[1] ) ;
    return 0 ;
}
```

If I re-compile it and re-run it, the vulnerability is gone:

```
gcc test.c -o test
./test %p%p%p
%p%p%p
```

Why is this happening, what changed from the first example?

Also, in the first example, shouldn't the *%s* in the *printf* consider *buf* as a string? Why is such code still affected by the format string vulnerability?

Comment: `%p%p%p` is lame, try `%n%n%n%n`

Comment: those extra spaces look awful. they make it *harder* to read what's happening

Comment: Well, you completely removed the vulnerable part, for one thing.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the output of the first snippet to match the second one, then simply use the same formatting specifier you used for `printf`, i.e.:

```
snprintf ( buf, sizeof buf, "%s", argv [1] );
                            ^^^^
```

In this case the `argv[1]` string is not treated as a formatting template for some other arguments, and you simply get `%p%p%p` written to `buf`.

Did you perhaps intend to *copy* the string instead? I am asking because `snprintf` automatically terminates the buffer, you don't need to set the null terminator manually (and this is [usually done when using `strncpy`](https://randomascii.wordpress.com/2013/04/03/stop-using-strncpy-already/)):

```
strncpy ( buf, argv [1], sizeof buf );
buf [ sizeof buf - 1 ] = 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

You're asking about format string vulnerability. Format string vulnerability occurs whenever an user-supplied string is used as the format to *any* `*scanf` or `*printf` function.

In the first fragment the vulnerability is with `snprintf`. In the second fragment your `printf` has the format string `"%s"`. It was not supplied by the user, therefore no vulnerability. Try

```
printf(buf);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
snprintf ( buf, sizeof buf, argv [1] ) ;
```

you have just abused snprintf as you have not passed the parameters to match your format string `%p%p%p`.

So you just have an UB.

You should for example (with the same format string)

```
snprintf ( buf, sizeof buf, argv [1], argv[0], buff, "Hello, Show where string literals are stored" ) ;
```